# How to control SVG template (click events) in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, frontend

In an Angular project I have an SVG map of a country, with all of its regions,
and I'm trying to put this SVG map as a template of a component.

So in the SVG file I have each region represented as `<path>` or `<polygon` element, in total more than 70 regions. And one of the requirements is to highlight each clicked region in a certain color.

Is there a way to handle the click event on each region ( `<path>` and  `<polygon` elements ), other than adding the `(click)` event on all of the 70 `<path>` and  `<polygon` elements, because that seems for me a lot code repetition

**Note**: here I cannot use a loop on the SVG elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewChild` or `ViewChildren` depending on your use-case.

This is a bit pseudo-codeish but it should help you getting started.

```js
@Component({
  ...
  template: `<svg #map>...<svg>`
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('map') map: HTMLElement // or SvgHTMLElement counterpart

  @HostListener('click')
  onMapComponentClicked(event: MouseEvent) {    
    const clickedElement = this.getClickedSvg(event)
    if(!clickedElement) return
    
    // Do something with the clicked SVG; maybe read it's ID
  }

  private getClickedSvg(event: MouseEvent): HTMLElement? {
    return ( 
      Array.from(this.map.children).find(el => el.contains(event.target))
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done it adding a click event on each svg element.
Of course you should not do it by yourself but you can navigate programatically in your dom elements and add the click event automatically.

I don't know how your code is but here an exampe:

```
<svg #mySvg></svg>
```

in the component.ts maybe something like this should work:

```js
@ViewChild('mySvg') mySvg: SVGElement;

// other code

const children = this.mySvg.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  const childElement = children[i];
  childElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // Do stuff
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an Angular way to do the navigation on the  elements of the svg ?

Comment: it's difficult to provide an example and it's not an "Angular way" but I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, it is Kind of hard to add a global listener in the Angular way, but the provided example is very useful